# Rails routing scope/namespace problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, namespaces

I am working on a project with several parts and developers. We use mongodb and thus declare the db stuff in the models. To only have one db although the project has several separated servers we store the models in a common directory and in a gem.

This means we have a namespace for the models, public_models

To avoid routes like /public_models/users/... I have declared the following route:

```
scope :module => "public_models" do
  resources :users
end
```

This works in many cases and generete the roures one would expect.

```
users     GET    /users(.:format)          public_models/users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          public_models/users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      public_models/users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) public_models/users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      public_models/users#show
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      public_models/users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      public_models/users#destroy
```

However I have to change several links to make it work. 
index.html.erb

```
link_to 'Show', user_path(user) instead of link_to 'Show', user
```

form_for I have to specify the url. The problem if I specify:

```
form_for @user, :url => user_path(:id => @user) do |f|
```

Then update works, but not new I get "No route matches [POST] "/user/287944764774"
If I change it to

```
form_for @user, :url => users_path(@user) do |f|
```

then new works like a charm but I get this error for update

```
"No route matches [PUT] "/user.287944764774"
```

Not to mention the redirect_to where I need to use:

```
redirect_to user_path(:id => @user.id)
```

This is all very confusing and weird! I mean it can't be the first time someone wants models stored in another place. Does it really have to destroy all form helpers etc. What is the proper way to do this???

Comment: Im having the same problem on rails 4.0, did you seem to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

i had lot of trouble with this issue before. The main reason it's hard to understand is, form_for and link to helpers are doing lot of work for us when used with simple models.

Before diving deeper, can i ask you to try

```
link_to 'Show', [:public_models, user]
```

and also, in a new dummy project, something like

```
rails g scaffold 'PublicModels::User' name:string
```

I m not sure if these are exact answers for your problems but i think they can give some clues about what's going on.

EDIT

about form submits, as you can see from routes output, path for post url (new) is

```
users_path
```

but for put url (edit) is

```
user_path(@user)
```

so you can try something like

```
:url => (@user.new_record? ? users_path : user_path(@user))
```

or just separate two form and handle url / method parameters in different code blocks

Comment: Well, the first dosen't work at all. The second just creates the scaffold and places views and controllers under app/views/public_models and app/controllers/public_models. It also creates a namespace route which dosen't really help. What I want is to be able to avoid the extra /public_models/ part of the url.                                                                I guess rails gets confussed as there is a namespace for controllers and views but not for models.

Comment: I can live with a lot of the stuff but its really bad that I can either new or update to workbut not both at the same time. I would like to avoid a if statement before the form_for part to determine which one to use.

Comment: The main reason for this is that for post url you dont need @user.id but for put url you need it. One way to deal with this is to provide different :url and :method for each form.

Comment: So just seperate new and edit forms, try different :urls for each.